# can we add line separator in custom navigation bar? how? in swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

**I want navigation bar like below:**

[image]

but with my code i am getting like this:

[image]

for normal navigationbar code:

```
 func setUpNavigationBar(){
    
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = CommonColor.navigationColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = CommonColor.navigationColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 2
   
    
    let menuImageView = UIImageView.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu8"))
    menuImageView.tintColor = .darkGray
    menuImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,y:0.0, width:25,height:25.0)
    menuImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    menuImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(menuClick)))
    let btnMenu = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuImageView)
    
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(btnMenu, animated: true)
            
    let logoImageView = UIImageView.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pic-logo"))
    logoImageView.tintColor = .darkGray
    logoImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,y:0.0, width:100,height:25.0)
    logoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.navigationItem.titleView = logoImageView


}
```

with the above code i am not getting line in navigationbar.. how to add height 1 view line separater in navigationbar with code

i am calling this in every `viewcontroller's viewwillappeadr **setUpNavigationBar**`

Comment: I don't think you can do this with NavigationBar bcz here your line will cover whole width for which u need to create a View instead of NavigationBar.

Comment: @Kudos you mean to add every time in each view controller?

Comment: Yess And PLease follow Apple Guidelines. Before Making any unusual UI make sure it validated with Apple UI Guidelines.